# Creating batches within an array containing images

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, chainer

I have an array `X_train` containing 9957 images. I am making a Convolutional network.The desired shape of the array for feeding into the model is (batchsize, channel, height, width)

```
X_train.shape #gives (9957, 60, 80, 3)
X_train[1].shape #gives (60, 80, 3)
```

If we use

```
np.reshape(X_train,(-1, 3, 60, 80)) #it gives (9957, 3, 60, 80)
```

How can I get each array with shape (batchsize, 3, 60, 80) and the final image array for training with shape(9957, batchsize, 3, 60, 80)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get from `i`-th image until `i + batchsize` image as follows.

```
batchsize = 16
i = 0

X_batch = X_train[i: i+batchsize]
print('X_batch.shape: ', X_batch.shape)  # it should be (16, 3, 60, 80)
```

Please change `i` with for loop to get each image. For example,

```
for i in range(0, len(X_train), batchsize):
    X_batch = X_train[i: i+batchsize]

    # --- Do something with X_batch ---
```

Comment: for some reason it changes the array shape into (5, 3, 60, 80).

Comment: 9957 == 16 * 622 + 5, 5 is the remainder. But you should first refer Chainer's official tutorial, which recommend you to use `chainer.datasets`

Comment: model = Sequential(
        L.Convolution2D(None, 128, 3, 2),
        F.relu,
        L.Convolution2D(128, 64, 3, 2),
        F.relu,
        L.Convolution2D(64, 32, 3, 2),
        F.relu,
        L.Linear(None, 16),
        F.dropout,
        L.Linear(16, 4)
    ) This being the model...my training set has the shape (9957, 3, 60, 80). Does it have the correct input_shape?

Comment: You are using `L.Convolution2D(None, 128, 3, 2)` as the first layer, and the first argument `None` means that the first layer's input channel size is automatically determined (in your case input data's channel size is 3). So it is ok to use this model.

In terms of height & width of the image, its size changes during the convolution operation, but again, when you input to `L.Linear(None, 16)`, its size is automatically determined.

Comment: My final image shape is (32,3,60,80) and label shape is (32,). Are both the image and label input_shape correct for training?

Comment: After 100 epochs my main accuracy and validation accuracy remains the same.

Comment: Yes..I am able to train the model. But it shows a gradually increasing main/training accuracy from 0.78 to 0.98 and validation accuracy changes from 0.79 to 0.66 after 100 epochs. Sometimes the main accuracy and validation accuracy doesn't change at all. I think these are signs of over-fitting. However I have tried adding dropout to the model but the main and validation accuracy changes very little(factor of 1).

Comment: I think it's not a bug of your program but this is the usual behavior of machine learning. It is not possible to 100% answer correct label of "unseen" validation data.

Comment: Is this model fit enough to predict label of images? Also what can I do to improve the accuracy of the model?